# Qual "mecanismo" de Diff o StackOverFlow usa?

Tags: suporte

Ao editarmos uma pergunta/resposta, o site salva um histórico e nos mostra o que foi alterado em cada versão. Essa forma de mostrar o que foi alterado no texto, se chama [Diff](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff).

A imagem abaixo explica melhor o que estou falando:

<kbd>[image: Diff SOpt]</kbd>

[Fonte da imagem.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/129209/revisions)

Bom, diante disse vem a minha pergunta:

A Stack Exchange já "liberou" alguns frameworks desenvolvidos por eles, como o [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net) e o [Mini Profiller](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet).

Em relação do Diff, a Stack Exchange criou algo? Se sim, está disponível para utilizarmos?

Caso não tenha desenvolvido o seu próprio framework, qual é o utilizado?

> Nota, me refiro ao Diff, e não ao layout de como é mostrado as alterações.

Comment: Realmente não achei essa informação, então pode ser algo "secreto" até alguém vir aqui contar :) Tem alguma chance de ser esse ou alguma variação dele: http://www.mathertel.de/Diff/. O problema em termos genéricos: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem

Comment: @bigown Eu procurei algo analisando o código gerado, mas também não encontrei nada. Bom, se realmente for secreto não faz problema, mas eu gostos de usar as coisas desenvolvidas pela Stack Exchange, até hoje me atenderam bem.
Mas obrigado por comentar.